# Checking if an item is "liked" by user or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of items that I loop inside the render and for each item I want to check if it has been liked by the current user using a function that checks for this correlation. The function requests the API to check the likes table returning true or false.

The code below will cause an infinite loop. Any ideas how to best fix this?

```
function exampleComponent() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [hasLike, setHasLike] = useState(null);
    const user = useContext(UserContext);

    useEffect(()=> {
        //I get and set the array of items here
    })


    function checkHasLike(itemId, userId) {
        axios.post('/api/check-like', {
            itemId: itemId,
            userId: userId
        }).then(response=> {
            setHasLike(response.data); //this should return true or false.
        }, ()=>{
            //handle rejection
        }).catch(()=>{
            //handle errors
        })
    }

    return(
        <>
            //Renders Page and all related stuff
            items.map(item => { //This is for displaying the item

                checkHasLike(item.id, user.id); //this will cause infinite loop...

                {hasLike? /*code for displaying already liked button*/ : /*active like button*/ }

            })
        </>
    )

}
```

Comment: Instead having to GET a separate endpoint, why not include that information in the items data?

Comment: The likes table contains additional information about the likes each individual user makes so I need to access it separately. thanks @Andy

Answer (score 0):

Do not call state update directly in the `render` function because the `render` function invokes re-render and call `render` function again

Use `useEffect` to make an API request/requests, something like this:

```js
  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios.post('/api/check-like', { items });
    setLikes(result.data);
  }, []);
```

Comment: `items` should be part of the dependency list of `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
const LIKE_STATUS={
NOT_DEFINED:0,
PROCESSING:1,
LIKED:2,
NOT_LIKED:3
}
function exampleComponent() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [hasLike, setHasLike] = useState(null);
    const user = useContext(UserContext);

    useEffect(()=> {
       const processingItemIds=[]
       items.forEach(item=>{
          if(!item.hasLike || item.hasLike===LIKE_STATUS.NOT_DEFINED){
              checkHasLike(item.id,userId);
              processingItemIds.push(item.id)
          }
       })
       setItems(items.map(item => 
           processingItemIds.includes(item.id)
               ? 
               ({...item,hasLike:LIKE_STATUS.PROCESSING})
               :
               item
              ))
    })


    function checkHasLike(itemId, userId) {
        axios.post('/api/check-like', {
            itemId: itemId,
            userId: userId
        }).then(response=> {
            setItems(items.map(item=>
                 item._id===itemId
                 ?
                 ({
                     ...item,
                     hasLike:response.data? 
                     LIKE_STATUS.LIKED:LIKE_STATUS.NOT_LIKED
                  })
                  :
                  item
             ); 
        }, ()=>{
            //handle rejection
        }).catch(()=>{
            //handle errors
        })
    }

    return(
        <>
            //Renders Page and all related stuff
            items.map(item => { //This is for displaying the item
                {hasLike? /*code for displaying already liked button*/ : /*active like button*/ }

            })
        </>
    )

}
```

Comment: `items` should be part of the dependency list of `useEffect`.

Comment: Aha so you are changing items through useEffect and you want to have likes only fetched ones for each item? If that is the case adding property hasLikes that has one of following values:
const LIKE_VALUES={
NOT_DEFINED:0,
PROCESSING:1,
LIKED:2,
NOT_LIKED:3
}
and sending request in useEffect only when item value for hasLike is 0 (not defined). Or if you like it more split it into 2 properties, hasLike and isProcessing so hasLike has values true/false/undefined and you send request when it is undefined and isProcessing is false.

Comment: @FelixKling i've updated answer based on new comment. Changing state in render is always bad idea, even if you know what you are doing it is possible someone else working on the project changes something that breaks it.

Comment: It's the first case @SenZo.
I'm trying to implement this solution. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the posts given this was my final working implementation.

```
function exampleComponent() {
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const user = useContext(UserContext);

/*Where I get the items I check if the item has a like and insert
'hasLike' property with the(true/false) value to the item in to the final array.*/
useEffect(()=> {
    setItems(await Promise.all(response.data.map(async item => {
        await checkHasLike(item, user.id);
        return item;
    })));
})

//checking if the item has a like and inserting the true/false value to the item.
async function checkHasLike(item, userId) {
    await axios.post('/api/check-like', {
        itemId: item.id,
        userId: userId
    }).then(response=>
        item['hasLike'] = response.data;
    }, ()=>{
        //handle rejection
    }).catch(()=>{
        //handle errors
    })
}

return(
    <>
        //Renders Page and all related stuff
        items.map(item => { //This is for displaying the item

            {item.hasLike? /*code for displaying already liked button*/ : /*active 
             like button*/ }

        })
    </>
)

}
```